# What is the default property of Graphics.Unit when no property is selected? [C#]

Tags: c#

What is the default property of GraphicsUnit when no property is selected?

`graphics.PageUnit = GraphicsUnit.?`

[image]

So when I'm drawing a string, which unit is being used?

```
 private void printDocument1_PrintPage(object sender, PrintPageEventArgs e)
 {
    e.Graphics.DrawString("String", textBox2.Font, Brushes.Black, 50);
 }
```

with reference to:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.drawing.graphics.pageunit(v=vs.100).aspx

**EDITED:**

Used Eris Approach modified into messagebox:

This Worked:

```
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(e.Graphics.PageUnit));
```

// **Answer Received:** Display

but this also worked:

```
MessageBox.Show(Convert.ToString(default(GraphicsUnit)));
```

// **Answer Received:** World.

Which one should be correct?

Comment: Please add more context around your code. What is `e`?

Comment: @DanielA.Thompson is it fine now?

Comment: Why not test it yourself in the debugger??

Comment: @TaW very newbie to this, can you tell me how would I check in debugger if the program is using a certain unit?

Comment: You write a line that sets a PageUnit. Then put a breakpoint on it. Then check the old value by moving the cursor over `e.Graphics.PageUnit`

Comment: @TaW actually I'm not using `e.Graphics.PageUnit` to set any unit, I'm just drawing a string, how would I know which unit is being used as a default when I'm setting nothing.?

Comment: You need to learn some basic debugging skills using breakpoints.

Comment: `Console.WriteLine(default(GraphicsUnit))` ?

Comment: @Eris check my edited question.

Comment: You always get an initialized Graphics object in your PrintPage event handler.  It always defaults to GraphicsUnit.Display.  Which provides scaling of 100 pixels per inch, making anything you draw to the printer about the same size as what you draw to the screen.  Change it only when you know what you are doing, it doesn't sound like you are there yet.  Do experiment before you ask for help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
public Form1 ()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    panel1.Invalidate(); //trigger paint
}

private void panel1_Paint ( object sender, PaintEventArgs e )
{
    var result = e.Graphics.PageUnit; //breakpoint here
}
```

Hover over `result`, it is the pixel. So by default, it appears that `e.Graphics.PageUnit` is defaulted to the pixel for a panel paint event at least.

Basic Debugging: trigger your event at question, breakpoint at `var result = object.variablename`, hover over result.

Comment: Answer Received: "Display"

Comment: Just want to ask one more thing, If I'm using Display Unit on different printers on different computers, is that better or using milimeters to get same result on every printer and computer?

Comment: That's an entirely new question and one that I don't know the answer to sadly